# Windows Phone In-app purchase: Add custom data to receipts

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to specify custom data that would be included in the product receipt after purchase?

The problem is that we have an app with authentication and each purchase should be tied to the current authenticated user instead of the PublisherUserId that is generated by the store. We'd rather have the receipt, if possible, to contain all the necessary data to identify the user and the purchase to simplify the process.

Thanks,
-Sami

Comment: I think you will have to store that information yourself on a server and then retrieve it when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

approach should be, as soon as purchase is completed - save the receipt from the store to local. Typically this receipt is in XML format, you can add your own custom data to this receipt content based on your needs and save it in your servers (if needed).

```
string receiptXml = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, true);
```